# rails respond_to json format to include two (or more) models and some of their virtual attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, respond-to

in one of my controller actions, I am assigning a project to a user, and I want to respond to json requests to it with some info about the user and some info about the project. I can, at the moment, see all of their database attributes like this:

```
    # ruby code...
    # current_user.first_name #=> "Nik" db attr
    # current_user.full       #=> "Nik So" virtual attr
    # @project.name           #=> "buy something"

    format.json { render json: {user:current_user), assignable:@project}}
```

So in my firebug console, I can see the response object in my console

```
    // JS code
    success: function(r){window.test = r}

    //in console
    test.user.first_name //"Nik"
    test.assignable.name //"buy something"
    test.user.full       //undefined
```

Any chance that I can return virtual attributes alongside my models in the JSON response?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!, here's a solution:

```
        format.json { render json: {user:current_user.as_json(methods:[:full]), assignable:@project}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works well for me:

```
SomeController
  respond_to :json


def some_action
  @response = { :user => current_user, :assignable => @project )
  respond_with @response
end
```